# How to create this kind of layout for android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, tableview

I have design of andorid layout I have no idea how to start the UI use what (grid, table layout or ). by this 
Please give me example.
Here is the design!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with nested LinearLayouts:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#dddddd" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="#ff4000" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#cccccc" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#ff8000" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#ffbf00" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#ff4000" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#facc2e" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#ffbf00" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#ff8000" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#ffbf00" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this tutorial can help you : http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/ , any way you can use only LinearLayout horizontal and vertical to do your UI